# Get the selected drop down list value from a FormCollection in MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a form posting to an action with MVC.  I want to pull the selected drop down list item from the FormCollection in the action.  How do I do it?

My Html form:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
    {%>
    <select name="Content List">
    <% foreach (String name in (ViewData["names"] as IQueryable<String>)) { %>
          <option value="<%= name %>"><%= name%></option>
    <% } %>
    </select>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Save" /></p>
<% } %>
```

My Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection)
{
    //how do I get the selected drop down list value?
    String name = collection.AllKeys.Single();
    return RedirectToAction("Details", name);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Start by giving your `select` tag a valid `name`. A valid name cannot contain spaces.

```
<select name="contentList">
```

and then fetch the selected value from the form parameters collection:

```
var value = collection["contentList"];
```

Or even better: don't use any collections, use an action parameter which has the same name as the name of your select and leave the default model binder populate it:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string contentList)
{
    // contentList will contain the selected value
    return RedirectToAction("Details", contentList);
}
```

Comment: Oh snap! Thanks, that did the trick.  I tried both ways but I like how you used the action parameter.